# IE browser not resuming PF cookie on refresh

Tags: pingfederate

I'm facing an issue with IE browser and Ping Federate 6.10. when user click refresh on end application, it will redirect to PF for user authentication (startSSO.ping URL) and display the same page after authentication.
chrome and firefox browsers make authentication done by using previous cookie information (seen from fiddler that StartSSO URL with cookie passed to PF) and display refreshed page again. In IE, previous cookie information are not passed with startSSO URL and it will go as a new request for PF and loads login page for user inputs.

changed my IE --> Internet options to accept all cookies, added the https site to trusted site and in Advanced Tab uncheck "check for publisher revocation& check for server certifate revocation" options.

We are facing same with IE10 & IE11 browsers. startSSO.ping is a https connection.

--------Refresh option in chrome, request to PF startSSO URL----------------

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:pfidpaid=devinthr; PF=rYymUDGNaAFFhAjXYHKpUzvpTYNotVKawlnxk0xlWGGJ
Host:192.168.2.1:9031
Referer:http://devint.ABCD.com/app/p2a/landing-page
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
```

-------same refresh in IE browser---------------------------

```
Request GET /idp/startSSO.ping?PartnerSpId=HRIM:SAML2:PRODUCTION-IDP&pfidpadapterid=devinthr&TargetResource=http://devint.ABCD.com/app/auth HTTP/1.1
Accept  application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*
Referer http://devint.ABCD.com/app/p2a/landing-page
Accept-Language en-US
User-Agent  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Connection  Keep-Alive
Host    192.168.2.1:9031
```

Any idea about this issue?

Thanks in Advance....

**EDITED:**
Noticed that while refresh chrome takes the intermediate URL cookie information and submit startSSO url to PF but could not found any where in browser about intermediate URL cookie information is stored..

I believe  this is what chrome and firefox can and IE can't with PF.

Comment: Those appear to be different transactions... But I can't tell without a full Fiddler trace, and I'm not going to ask for one here. Please open a case with PingIdentity.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I will post my question on PingIdentity. one clarification, I saw PF cookie contains Maxage attribute and came to know IE does not support maxage attribute. MaxAge is set to -1(serving as a session cookie).